# appending new items to isotope

Tags: ajax, jquery-isotope

I dont't seem to be able to append new items to isotope no matter what I try. I wanna do it after an ajax request.

The closest I've come to is the following in my `success` callback:

```
$('.storiesiso').append( response ).isotope( 'reloadItems' ).isotope({ sortBy: 'original-order' }).isotope('layout');
```

Using that, the items ARE actually added but they are set to `display:none` and have no `right` or `top` css stying applied to them.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using the isotope methods to do that?
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/docs/adding-items.html

The `appended` or `insert` method can be used after your response is filled:

```
var $newItems = $('<div class="item" /><div class="item" /><div class="item" />');
$('#container').isotope( 'insert', $newItems );
```